# Read File in SAP UI 5

Tags: sapui5

I am looking for a possibility to read a file in SAP UI 5.

I tried it with the fileuploader, but I see no possibility to get the content of the selected file locally.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution a few minutes later in this thread:

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3782341

To achieve the solution, check this JsBin:

http://jsbin.com/fenexuqule/edit?html,output